# Pivot for multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have 3 areas:

```
Melt, HSM, LSM
```

each order produced in some areas with following data:

```
Start Date, Finish Date, Weight
```

I have a `View`in `SQL Server 2012`(top image), How can I create a pivot that generate bottom image, using tsql?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT [Order],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'Melt' THEN StartDate   END) AS Melt_SDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'Melt' THEN FinisthDate END) AS Melt_FDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'Melt' THEN Weight      END) AS Melt_Weight,

    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'HSM' THEN StartDate    END) AS HSM_SDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'HSM' THEN FinisthDa    END) AS HSM_FDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'HSM' THEN Weight       END) AS HSM_Weight,

    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'LSM' THEN StartDate    END) AS LSM_SDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'LSM' THEN FinisthDate  END) AS LSM_FDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'LSM' THEN Weight       END) AS LSM_Weight
FROM tab_name
GROUP BY [Order];   -- ORDER is reserved word, you should avoid such identifiers;
```

To make it more concise you could use `IIF`:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN Area = 'Melt' THEN StartDate   END) AS Melt_SDate,
<=>
MAX(IIF(Area='Melt',StartDate,NULL)) AS Melt_SDate,
```

Comment: In performance POV, this way is better or using `Pivot` function?

Comment: performance should be better than `Pivot` since you'd have to pivot 3 times to get the same result